Stopping gentile from wrongdoing
Am I Mechuyav (as an employee) to stop a non-Jew (your boss) from stealing, damaging etc (i.e throwing things away that dont belong to him) from a non-Jew (employee) who violated company policy, so therefore the non-Jew can throw out that persons belongings. What if it’s not company policy?
etc?
